# How to duplicate a package within the same project (but with a different name)

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Suppose I have some `ProjectA` with structure `ProjectA.src.folder_a`. I want to *duplicate* `folder_a` into `folder_b` (exact copies), both within `ProjectA.src`. For example, with the same contents:

`ProjectA.src.folder_a`
`ProjectA.src.folder_b`

However CTRL+C/V will not result in an updating of the `package` and `import` declarations to `folder_b` in each classes premable.

How to fix/do?

The process I go through which doesn't work:

`1)` Create `folder_b` in `ProjectA.src`.

`2)` Copy over all sub-folders using CTRL+C, manually naming each to `ProjectA.src.folder_b.insert_sub_folder_name`, from the default copy name of `ProjectA.src.folder_a.insert_sub_folder_name.copy`

`3)` Copy all files from `folder_a` into `folder_b`.

`4)` Observe preamble of class files, see that `package` is now correct but `imports` still refer to `ProjectA.src.folder_a....` whereas I want them to refer to `ProjectA.src.folder_b.....`.

Comment: It works for me. Select all classes in package `folder_a`. Copy them. Paste them in package `folder_b`. Is your `src` folder designated as a source folder?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not sure how to check this? I also have sub-folders in `a`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis None of the import references are updated. THey still refer to `project_a`.

Comment: Are you given the option to name the nested target package when you CTRL+V?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The package reference is fixed but the imports still refer to `a` and not `b`'s subfolders.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you take pics of each step you do or describe it in more detail?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `1)` Create `folder_b` in `ProjectA.src`. `2)` Copy over all sub-folders using CTRL+C, manually naming each to `ProjectA.src.folder_b.insert_sub_folder_name`, from the default copy name of `ProjectA.src.folder_a.insert_sub_folder_name.copy` `3)` Copy all files from `folder_a` into `folder_b`. `4)` Observe preamble of class files, see that `package` is now correct but `imports` still refer to `ProjectA.src.folder_a....` whereas I want them to refer to `ProjectA.src.folder_b.....`.

Comment: Oh, it's the imports that don't work. I don't think Eclipse can fix that. It can't know which classes you are referring to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So I need to manually rename everything if I want to copy stuff?

Comment: I would think so, yes. I may be wrong...